# Click off menu/div to close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make my menu close when I click anywhere on the page except for within the menu.

I managed to achieve this for when a link is clicked within the menu by giving it the same onclick function as the menu button, but I am not succeeding at clicking off the menu to close it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEvdmW

JS

```
function setVisibility(id) {
  var targetButton;
  switch( id ) {
    case "layer":
      targetButton = "button";
      break;
  }
  if (document.getElementById(targetButton).value == 'Close') {
    document.getElementById(targetButton).innerHTML = 'Open';
    document.getElementById(targetButton).value = 'Open';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(targetButton).innerHTML = 'Close';
    document.getElementById(targetButton).value = 'Close';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button name="type" id="button" onclick="setVisibility('layer')">Open</button>
<div id="layer"><a onclick="setVisibility('layer')"> Hello</div>
```

CSS

```
#layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #989898;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    display: none;
}


button {  border:none; background:#989898; color:#fff; padding:10px; outline:none; cursor:pointer;

}
```

Comment: are you restricted to javascript solution or you can alos jQuery?

Comment: jquery also, sorry I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be achieved via below code.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/153/

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCB5W/154/

Comment: will do, just trying to implement it to my existing code, having a little trouble getting it to work at the moment. Your fiddle works nicely though

Comment: I just wasn't able to get this to work with my code @Jitendra I'm probably misunderstanding something quite simple

Comment: Place your menu html in the question.

Comment: I've added it now @Jitendra

Comment: Thanks, I put #layer in as per your comment, but I must have messed it up in the copy/paste when I tested it because it didn't work. Your fiddle does though. Awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can have a backdrop behind the div where you have your onclick event to hide the div. Check the modified code below (modified your code for you to understand):

Working example : [DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jERzvo?wb48617274=2C37F57B)

HTML

```
<button name="type" id="button" onclick="setVisibility('layer')">Open</button>
<div id="backdrop" onclick="setVisibility('layer')"></div>
<div id="layer">Hello</div>
```

CSS

```
#layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    z-index : 999;
}

#backdrop {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    background : black;
    opacity : 0.5;
    z-index : 2;
    display : none;
}

button {  
    border:none; 
    background:#989898; 
    color:#fff; 
    padding:10px; 
    outline:none; 
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS

```
function setVisibility(id) {
  var targetButton;
  switch( id ) {
    case "layer":
      targetButton = "button";
      break;
  }
  if (document.getElementById(targetButton).value == 'Close') {

    document.getElementById(targetButton).innerHTML = 'Open';
    document.getElementById(targetButton).value = 'Open';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = "none"; 

  } else {

    document.getElementById("backdrop").style.display = "block"; 
    document.getElementById(targetButton).innerHTML = 'Close';
    document.getElementById(targetButton).value = 'Close';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue I have with this is the layer behind absorbs the click. So if I click off and onto a link, I must click twice. Once to close the menu and a second time to click the link on the page.

Comment: I dont think so..have u tried..? For same reason i m using z-index...backdrop will remain behind the div

Comment: Whether you meant that if there is any link on page, even outside div, you should be able to click it and at same tym your div should also hide..?

Comment: it more looks a popup rather than a menu.